# JBoss 6.1.0 - JMX-Console war not getting deployed

Tags: java, deployment, jmx, jboss6.x

When i try to access URL: http://myhost.com/jmx-console/

I do not see anything, no error nothing on web page.

In server.log i see this message coming up, and nothing else:

> WARN  [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.ondemand.OnDemandContextProfileManager] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-2) Profile ProfileKey@18c0487[**domain=default**, server=default, name=jmx-console.war] is already activated

When i see this location:
JBOSS_HOME/server/mydomain/work/jboss.web/localhost
I see all web-app directories like admin_console, invoker, jbossws, myapp
But i do not see jmx-console. It should have been there.

The war itself exists in its original location of JBOSS_HOME/common/deploy/jmx-console.war

One problem i see is that the WARN message refers to **domain=default**, although my JBoss server domain is different (mydomain). Where should i correct this, if that is the problem area.

Comment: Is the URL you tried 0.0.0.0:8680/jmx-console/?

Comment: No.. my application works fine, i tried my actual host name with port. So i am accessing correct URL i think